# React-native running offline bundle error no script URL provided

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, react-native

I am trying to run a completely offline bundle of my app only once to test if the microphone is working and failing to do so.
I have read other threads and github issues but I have a rather weird setup:

My OSX machine (sierra) is running inside a VM (I do not have access to a Mac) so the iphone (5s running 10.2) and the OSX probably do not appear to be on the same network (because the host is connected to the same WIFI as the iphone but the VM is using NAT).

I can bundle correctly with `react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle` and

1) added the file to the project
2) set scheme target to release

the build success but I get after running

> No script URL

is it possible to just put the main.jsbundle somehow in the iphone and just test it (it doesn't need any dev servers)? I do not care about debugging I just want to load it as you can do with an .apk in android.
Why does it have to connect to any URL?

Comment: Is `main.jsbundle` file actually exists in you `APPNAME.app` bundle directory?

Comment: it's in APPROOT/ios/main.jsbundle

Comment: RN packer places it in APPROOT/main.jsbundle

Comment: but the command in FB documentation say to use --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle. What should I do? copy it over in APPROOT?

Comment: Docs places to you project folder in `<project>/ios/main.jsbundle` (probably because it allows split files for various platforms), but in final application bundle it will be in `<app>/main.jsbundle` see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/packager/react-native-xcode.sh#L86 script (this script called when you build the project in Xcode)

Comment: I really don't understand why you have to manually bundle the main.jsbundle.

Just by setting the scheme in Xcode as RELEASE, and running the project, the react-native bundler will automatically create the `main.jsbundle` for you and run the project in your simulator.

Creating an (.ipa) pretty much like the .apk of Android, is not that easy in iOS. For many reasons. There's a hell of provisioning profiles that you have to go through.

Comment: As stated in the question, the code runs in the simulator but not when connected to an iPhone due to probably running osx in a VM and network issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem doesn't exist if I am using the package https://github.com/mcnamee/react-native-starter-app in my VM.

Answer (score 3):

As @vovkasm mentioned, it's worth checking whether the `main.jsbundle` file is actually included in the compiled `.app`. You can find it in the "Products" directory then right click on it in Finder and "Show Package Contents" the `main.jsbundle` should be listed in there.
If not then you need to add `main.jsbundle` to your Xcode project.

For me the bundle file was showing up in the project sidebar but wasn't actually added to the project properly.

Comment: This comment finally solved it for me.
1. In Xcode left-hand pane, open [ProjectName]/Products
2. Right-click ProjectName.app -> Show in Finder
3. Right-click in Finder -> Show Package Contents

My main.jsbundle wasn't there - it was in my project but had a question mark next to it, I readded it and it worked.

Thanks!

Comment: i am having same problem how do i add main.jsbundle  file in packege?